# Issue with STM32F103CBT6 and Rotary Encoders: Unreliable Input

Tags: c, stm32

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a PCB design using an STM32F103CBT6 microcontroller, coupled with a 16 MHz crystal oscillator, 18 buttons, and 4 rotary encoders. The PCB is programmed to function as an HID device game controller. While I have successfully programmed the buttons, I'm encountering some problems with the rotary encoders.

The issue I'm confronting is that not every click of the rotary encoder is being recognized as input. On occasion, a rotation of the encoder is either skipped or not detected, resulting in missed input. Additionally, it appears that the encoder occasionally "jumps" from one pin to another, resulting in input from the wrong pin or, in some cases, both pins of the encoder registering input simultaneously.

I am using the EC11 rotary encoders. The middle pin of each encoder is connected to ground, while the other two pins are connected to separate pins on the MCU. Encoder 1 is connected to pins PB8 and PB9, encoder 2 to pins PB10 and PB11, encoder 3 to pins PB12 and PB13, and encoder 4 to pins PB14 and PB15. All these pins are configured as GPIO inputs with internal pull-up resistors.

I suspect that my approach to programming the rotary encoders may not be correct, but I lack expertise in programming. I'm hopeful that someone can guide me in the right direction.

Here's a summary of my PCB configuration:

Microcontroller: STM32F103CBT6
Crystal Oscillator: 16 MHz
Number of rotary encoders: 4
Number of buttons: 18
I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Code 1 I used, but this code is worse of the 2:

```
#define ROT_PINS 8
#define ROT_BUTTONS 8

GPIO_TypeDef* rotary_ports[ROT_BUTTONS] = {GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB};
uint16_t rotary_pins[ROT_BUTTONS] = {GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_15};

struct ButtonReport {
    uint8_t report_id;
    uint32_t buttons; 
} __attribute__((packed));

struct ButtonReport buttonReport;

void SCANALL(void)
{
    uint8_t targetRow, targetCol;

    // Clear the buttonReport struct
    memset(&buttonReport, 0, sizeof(buttonReport));

    // Scan encoders (knoppen 1-8)
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        uint8_t rotaryStatus = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(rotary_ports[i], rotary_pins[i]);
        if (rotaryStatus == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
            buttonReport.buttons |= (1 << i);
        } else {
            buttonReport.buttons &= ~(1 << i);
        }
    }
    // Stuur het rapport met de knopstatussen
    buttonReport.report_id = 1; // Stel het rapport-ID in als dat nodig is
    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&buttonReport, sizeof(buttonReport));
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks all for the replies. I wasn't familiar with interrupts. I have studied the working of it and made a new code using one pin of a encoder as interrupt (falling) pin with internal pull up resistor, the other pin set as gpio_input with internal pull-up resistor. For now i am coding just the one encoder. The code is working, but I still have the issue that it is jumping between input when rotating the encoder.

```
struct ButtonReport {
    uint8_t report_id;
    uint32_t buttons;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct ButtonReport buttonReport;

int encoderState = 0;
int lastEncoderState = 0;

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_8 || GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_9) {
        encoderState = (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8) << 1) | HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9);
        int encoderChange = lastEncoderState - encoderState;

        // Clear button status initially
        buttonReport.buttons = 0;

        if (encoderChange == 1 || encoderChange == -3) {
            // Clockwise rotation - Simulate Button 1 press
            buttonReport.report_id = 1; // Set the report ID (if required)
            buttonReport.buttons |= 0x01; // Set Button 1 as pressed
        } else if (encoderChange == -1 || encoderChange == 3) {
            // Counterclockwise rotation - Simulate Button 2 press
            buttonReport.report_id = 1; // Set the report ID (if required)
            buttonReport.buttons |= 0x02; // Set Button 2 as pressed
        }

        lastEncoderState = encoderState;

        // Send the HID report to the PC
        USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&buttonReport, sizeof(buttonReport));
    }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB10 PB12 PB14 PB8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB11 PB13 PB15 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}
```

Comment: [No 10K resistors?](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ibb.co%2F7bLdcbS%2FEC11-VER-20-CIR.jpg&tbnid=hELKgTWleKECxM&vet=12ahUKEwj3v8bIi5GCAxWFPt4AHTjvCmQQMygBegQIARA2..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.robotics.org.za%2FEC11-VS-15&docid=r29fgs-0uIeG3M&w=371&h=265&q=stm%20ec11%20power&ved=2ahUKEwj3v8bIi5GCAxWFPt4AHTjvCmQQMygBegQIARA2)

Comment: I don't really get how the de-bouncing is done. Busy-delays `HAL_Delay(1);` is code smell. And most switches/encoders etc will need more than 1ms to settle.

Comment: It's really unclear to me why you are _writing_ to pins for the encoder. Normally these would be two _inputs_ which you read and monitor the phase difference as they change.

Comment: Why not use interrupts? I don't know much about STM32 but for encoders or really any fast digital signals, interrupts are used. Some controllers even have dedicated peripherals for handling encoders. As for the 10k resistors that @HansPassant suggested, you should use those, or set the GPIOs with an internal pull up/down

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that in STM32 timers have hardware support for encoders? I also recommend to read [this](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Drehgeber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your STM32 has a bunch of timers (TIM1-TIM5, and TIM8) which all support rotary encoders in hardware. Once you configure them in this mode, there is literally nothing more you need to do.

If the encoder gets rotated clockwise, the timer increments. If it gets rotated anti-clockwise, the timer decrements.

No ISRs, or really anything, required in software. I've worked on such a project recently, and I had to write almost no code.

This assumes that you have some control over which GPIO pins the encoders are connected to. Only some pins can be connected to the various timers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the timers! i have set 3 encoders to tim1, tim2 and tim4. The problem is i have 1 encoder to pins pb12 and pb13. pb12 is tim1_bkin and pb13 is tim1_ch1n, what i have read i can't use the tim1_bkin and pin pb13 shares tim1 with another encoder, so for this encoder i need to find another solution i guess. I have made an code, but can't test it for another 7 hours.

Comment: After further investigation unfortunately i can't use the timers, encoder mode of the timer require channel 1 and 2 of each one, and the pins i used are encoder1 tim4_ch3 & tim4_ch4, encoder 2 tim2_ch3 & tim2_ch4, encoder 3 tim1_bkin & tim1_ch1n, encoder 4 tim1_ch2n & tim1_ch3n

Comment: I've set up my new PCB with encoder pins connected to their respective timer channel 1 and channel 2 pins. Despite aiming for minimal code, I'm struggling to make it work. For Encoder 1, I want clockwise to correspond to bit 0 and counter-clockwise to bit 1, and for Encoder 2, bit 2 and bit 3. And those inputs will be send via a hid report.

Comment: You should post a new question detailing your new setup, and show us your new code.

Comment: Ok, i will do that, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459125/programming-rotary-encoder-with-timers

Comment: @Djowwie User 'wek' has given you an answer on that question, which is correct. If you don't understand it, ask for clarification. But in summary: don't use interrupts or callbacks on your timers. Just poll them. If the count has gone up, the switch has been turned one way. If it goes down, it was turned the other way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize 2 GPIOs per encoder. To detect rotation direction.

   - Set GPIOs as pull-up
   - Set one GPIO per encoder as an interrupt pin
2. When an interrupt occurs at an encoder, read the non-interrupt pin. If the non-interrupt pin is low then direction is, say left. If it is high then it is right. Or vice versa.
3. Don't use software debouncing if you can help it. It would unnecessarily effect your processor. Instead use appropriate capacitors on the signal lines.

Comment: Just a guess... Would a schottky diode work better for hw debounce?

Comment: I have edited my post. I have read in to interrupt pins and made an code. When rotating an encoder it will now trigger the code and send input to the pc. But it still jumps between pins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to resolve my issue is by revising the PCB pin assignments. This provides a great opportunity to reorganize the components on the pcb. I've made some edits to the rotary encoders, allocating them to channel 1 and channel 2 of every timers available: encoder 1 to PA0 and PA1 (Timer2), encoder 2 to PA6 and PA7 (Timer3), encoder 3 to PA8 and PA9 (Timer1), and encoder 4 to PB6 and PB7 (Timer4). Additionally, I've added 10k resistors to each pin connected to the 3.3V line. I've also made adjustments to the button matrix, assigning row pins to PB12 through PB14, and column pins to PB0, PB1, PB2, and PB4.

[Picture of button matrix and encoder wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rUHE.png)